# Partial derivatives of radial basis function?

Tags: partial-derivative

Assume I have a $N$-dimensional variable $X \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and a [radial basis function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel) $K(X,X')\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ centered on $X' \in \mathbb{R}^N$:

$$K(X,X')=-\exp\left(\frac{\lVert{X-X'}\rVert^2}{2h^2}\right)$$

with

$$X=\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{N}
         \end{bmatrix}$$

I want to evaluate the partial derivatives $\nabla K(X,X') = (\frac{\partial K(X,X')}{\partial x_1}, \ldots, \frac{\partial K(X,X')}{\partial x_N})$ at location $X$.

Now I could probably evaluate these derivatives numerically through finite differences. An analytic derivation would be more elegant, but seems quite daunting a task. Do you know if there is an elegant solution to this?

Comment: Automatic differentiation?